# jQuery not linking to rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am building my first application using Ruby on Rails.  I am trying to work a little jQuery into my rails view and I can't seem to get it synced up.  The view has

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.11.3.min.js', 'jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js' 'script.js' %>
```

in script.js I am (currently) running a very simple code partially to make sure I have the documents properly linked it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('th').click(function(){
     $(this).addClass('red');
  });
});
```

and the css is

```
.red{
   color:red;
}
```

but when I load the page on my localhost the jQuery doesn't work.

I am using Chrome so I ran the "inspect element" and it is generating an error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

I have jquery-1.11.3.min.js and jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js both required in application.js and loaded in to public/javascripts.

Why is the most basic jQuery syntax not being recognized?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you run 'rails new app' command already includes Jquery as default. There is no need of specifying Jquery on your javascript tag. You should be doing something similar <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Comment: read this tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/book . That is how I learned rails a while ago.

Comment: The problem is either your JS code get executed before jQuery library loads or it is not loading the jQuery at all.